# Cron wont save python script to txt file

Tags: python, date, cron, temperature

I've got a problem with my python script. I'd like to save data from serial, with python script to txt file every 5 minutes.

My Cron script:

```
*/5 * * * * root /home/user/temperature.py >> /home/user/temperature.txt
```

My python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# pytemp.py

import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600, timeout=10)
read = ser.read(5)
comp = read.split()
ser.close();
print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), comp[0]
```

Cron creates file temperature.txt but it's empty.

If I'm runing script with command python temperature.py it works fine showing me date and temperature.

Can anyone help me with it?

//EDIT:

Hey,

I found error - my folder with python's script wasn't chmoded correctly. I changed destination of script and now it's ok, but I see something wrong in my script. Temperature is shown as:

```
2013-03-16 13:40:01 166.8
2013-03-16 13:41:02 1617.
```

and it should look like:

```
20013-03-16 13:40:01 16.68
```

for example.

How can I edit my python script?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
*/5 * * * * root python /home/user/temperature.py >> /home/user/temperature.txt
```

?